# ASPxCalendar in DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, detailsview

Im using ASPxCalendar in EditItemTemplate in DetailsView Control.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                                <dxe:ASPxCalendar ID="ASPxCalendar2" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("DateEnd") %>' ClientInstanceName="calDateEndClient">
                                </dxe:ASPxCalendar>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
```

Ive noticed that when SelectedDate='<%# Bind("DateEnd") %>' is set I cant use javascript to change MinDate or SelectedDate etc. When I try to set SelectedDate selection simply dissapears, when I want to setMinDate nothing happens.

When SelectedDate property isnt set, javascript works correctly.

Is it known issue? Can I do anything to control ASPxCalendar control from javascript when It bounded to filed from DataSource ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the editor's Value, not the SelectedDate property.  In this case, everything should work properly:

```
<dxe:ASPxCalendar ID="ASPxCalendar2" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("DateEnd") %>' ClientInstanceName="calDateEndClient">
                                </dxe:ASPxCalendar>
```